# Nodejs Wait for all promises to resolve and then redirect

Tags: node.js, express, promise, express-fileupload

I am facing the problem in redirecting to index page. Instead page refreshes to same create page perhaps due to large size images are still copying but why page refreshing instead of images waiting copying to finish and then redirecting.

```
    module.exports.create_customModel_post = async (req, res) => {
    const {images} = req.files
    
    let myPromise = []

    if (images) {
        const dir = `./public/${req.body.slug}`
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
        
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            const uploadTo = `${dir}/${images[i].name}`            

            myPromise.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                
                images[i].mv(uploadTo, (err) => {                    
                    if(err){
                        reject(err);
                    }else{
                        resolve(uploadTo);
                    } 
                });
            }));            
        }
    }    
    
    Promise.all(myPromise).then(function(values) {
        console.log(values),
        // THIS REDIRECT IS NOT WORKING
        res.redirect('/admin/custom-models')
    }).catch(function (reasons) {
        console.log(reasons);
    });    
}
```

Response from server

```
POST /admin/create-custom-model - - ms - -
new model is created & saved
[
  './public/testing/attachment_48549925.svg',
  './public/testing/brand-name.png',
  './public/testing/design.svg',
  './public/testing/model-name.png',
  './public/testing/path9080.png',

]
GET /admin/create-custom-model 200 12.375 ms - -
```

here is form I am using. Removed extra

```
<main>
    <section class="">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Create Custom Model</h1>
            <table class="">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                 
                  
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="images" multiple>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/admin/custom-models">Cancel</a> </td>
                        <td><button type="submit" >Save</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Is it really true that the `mv` method callback takes a single error param?  no success param?

Comment: I did not understand exactly your question. but files does move without error, it just take time. and during this time page refreshes.

Comment: images[i].mv is express-fileupload function to move files to destination directory.

Comment: What exactly is the http response your server is sending?

Comment: POST /admin/create-custom-model - - ms - -
new model is created & saved
[  '...']
GET /admin/create-custom-model 200 12.375 ms - -

Comment: @danh that is indeed how it works ~ https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/blob/master/lib/utilities.js#L64

Comment: @MuhammadAmir You haven't shared the raw http response that the client receives but rather the server access log. Still, from what we can see there, it works as expected - the client makes a POST request, receives the redirect, and then fetches the redirect target with a GET request. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Bergi sorry I am not sure what you are asking. are you asking about chrome network tab data

Comment: @Bergi the redirect should be `/admin/custom-models` (according to OP's code) but is actually `/admin/create-custom-model`

Comment: @MuhammadAmir are you sure your app is running the code in your question? Have you made sure all changes are saved and the server is restarted? If you're using `nodemon`, try stopping and restarting it

Comment: @Phil I am working on this problem several days and restarted computer several time. Also restarted vscode a couple of time to check if there is any bug.

even commented out all code in controller to check if same controller is working. no problem found. 

If a small files upload then code works as expected but when larges files get uploaded page refreshes but images and database does get updated.

Comment: @MuhammadAmir that kind of sounds like a client-side problem. How are you making the request? What triggers the request to start?

Comment: @phil I am using the post form to upload the file no ajas.

I just check right now by uploading 12 images of 10kb each and code worked fine (it redirected to right location), it is just due to large file size.

Comment: @Bergi the problem is when I upload a large image it takes time to copy to folder but the code reaches to end and refresh the page instead wait for files to finish copying.
if my the end of code files have copied to location then code works perfectly fine.

Comment: What makes you think it reaches the end (I presume you mean the `then` handler with the `res.redirect()` call) without waiting for the copying to finish?

Comment: @bergi I wrapped Promised.all(myPromise).then() inside a setTimeout and set it to 20 second time. The page refreshed instantly and after 20 second I saw resolve log.

Comment: @MuhammadAmir That sounds like something else (not in the code you posted so far) is also responding to the request.